# Saving multiple records for later use

Tags: mysql, asp.net

I'm creating a website in which Im retrieving multiple records at a time. I have to save these records somewhere so I could later display them in a repeater control. So is there a way to save them. Arrays can't be used because they won't make the code generic and I want it to be more generic

```
    string query = @"select friend_id from selfify.user where email=('" + email + "');";

                MySqlConnection ms = new MySqlConnection(connection);
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, ms);
                ms.Open();
              MySqlReader r= new MySqlReader();
              r=cmd.executeQuery();
                while(r.Read()){
                 friend_id= r["friend_id"].ToString(); //if there are multiple records they
                                                      // cant be store in a variable
}

                Repeater1.DataSource = friend_id;
                Repeater1.DataBind();

                ms.Close();
```

Comment: Without further information the answer would be: "sure you can save them. Insert them into a table in your mysql db.". Have you tried that? What exactly is your problem? Please provide us some code of what you've tried so far.

Comment: @wullxz Im creating a social networking site in which I have to retrieve a bunch of images and then display them but the problem is that I don't understand how to add them to repeater control without initially saving them in a variable or something. And if I use array to store each record then it won't be predictable as I don't know how many records would be fetched at run time. I hope you get my point

Comment: The thing is: SO is a site where you get help solving problems with code. Nobody here will now start to code your whole website for you. You need to provide us some code. And tell us where in the code your problem is. I guess you already started to build some basic HTML layout? Well, because code might depend on the way your HTML looks like, we need that code to help you.

Comment: Put your extra data in session, you can save any type of data in it.